# interact with API added by k8s operator using native k8s python client

Tags: python, kubernetes

It's possible to talk to k8s's API, for instance talking to CoreV1Api:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
k8s_corev1_api = client.CoreV1Api()
k8s_corev1_api.read_namespaced_service("myservice", 'default')
```

If I add an operator to k8s, for instance [redis-operator](https://github.com/spotahome/redis-operator), this operator adds an API endpoint `redisfailover` to k8s. Is it possible to interact with it using native [k8s Python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `redisfailover` is actually a [Custom Resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/), created by the Redis Operator. You can interact with custom resources with the [CustomObjectsApi](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md), very similarly to your above example:

```
api = client.CustomObjectsApi()
api.get_namespaced_custom_object(
    group='databases.spotahome.com',
    version='v1',
    namespace='default',
    plural='redisfailovers',
    name='myredisfailover'
)
```